# I need Linux code that will delete my directories

Tags: linux

I need a linux code that will delete a directory.

I tried rm file_name code but it doesn't work

Comment: code for which language?

Comment: **What does "doesn't work" mean?** What happened when you tried it?  Did you get an error message? If you did get an error, paste the entire message instead of paraphrasing. Did you get incorrect results?  Did you get *no* results?  If the results were incorrect, what made them incorrect?  What were you expecting instead?  Did you get *any* correct results?  If so, what were they?

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to remove directories:
`rmdir myFolder`

If you're trying to remove a directory with all its content, including its subdirectories, use it with recursive tag: `rm -r myFolders`

Answer (score 0):

`rmdir Folder_name` -> To remove an empty directory

`rmdir -r Folder_name` -> To remove a directory that contains files or other directories(remove a folder recursively).